# How to pronounce "CEEAUS", "ICNALE", etc.?

Tags: pronunciation, acronyms

Are there rules for pronunciation of acronyms?

There seems that acronyms are pronounced differently, for example, TESOL /ti-soul/, UCL /yu-ci-el/. Could I generalize a rule based on my limited observation?

The rule is that if the acronym is formed like an English word, like a consonant or a cluster of consonants, a vowel, and then a consonant, and a vowel, it will be pronounced like an English word, and if the acronym is formed not like an English word, it will be pronounced letter by letter.

> "CEEAUS" for "The Corpus of English Essays Written by Asian University
>   Students"; "ICNALE" for "The International Corpus Network of Asian
>   Learners of English"

Thanks.

Comment: "CEEAUS" for "The Corpus of English Essays Written by Asian University Students";
"ICNALE" for "The International Corpus Network of Asian Learners of English"

Comment: When in doubt, spell it out. (Till someone says it's better to NOT say every letter!)

Comment: If the acronym has an obvious pronunciation, use it.  Otherwise, spell it out.  Not every acronym is intended to be pronounced.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there are no rules of pronunciation, just are there are no rules for the pronunciation of  English words from their spelling in general.

1. Sometimes an acronym is deliberately designed to sound like an existing word, for example [NICE](http://www.nice.org.uk/), the **N**ational **I**nstitute for Health and **C**are **E**xcellence. In those cases the intention from the get-go is to pronounce it as a word. It would be uncouth not to.
2. Other organisations have unpronounceable acronyms, e.g. [RNC](http://www.rnc.ac.uk/), and they are spoken as a series of letters.
3. Some look sufficiently unambiguous that their pronunciation is considered 'obvious'. Example: [UNESCO](http://en.unesco.org/)
4. The remainder normally start by being pronounced as letters and the pronunciation evolves over time: usually until some bright spark comes up with a really appealing way of saying them.

**Note**

While I was typing my answer, the question was edited to propose a rule. I don't think it is as easy as that.  You would have to cite many examples in order to justify it and just a couple of exceptions would make it unusable.

Comment: You are right about the use of "rule". I should have used "an assumption of a possible rule based on limited personal observations"@chasly from UK

Comment: I think there are _some_ rules about pronunciation of Englisf with respect to orthography. There are just a lot of one-off exceptions

Comment: The OP didn't update the question, user Rathony added the meanings of CEEAUS and ICNALE, and formatted that extra information. The "rule" which you speak of was contained in the original version but it was in a small wall of text (no paragraphs).

Comment: +1 It's good to remember that names and terms are invented, and the preferred pronunciations idiosyncratic, even when abreviated. The name of [USAID](https://www.usaid.gov/) is obvious, but , to every last person I know working in development or foreign relations, it is *U-S-A-I-D*, never *US aid* (to avoid ambiguity, leaving aside whether USAID's aid actually aids anyone). And while the [NCAA](http://www.ncaa.com/) is commonly *N C double-A*, the [AARP](http://www.aarp.org/) is never the *double-A R P*.

Comment: It seems that there is no way to pronounce acronyms or abbreviations right without pure luck or without repetitive confirmation passed mouth by mouth from native speakers. This is another difficulty that non-natives have in acquiring nativeness@choster